# Apache server only shows php page from host computer browser and not from other devices

Tags: php, apache, webserver

here is my httpd.conf file

`<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:81> DocumentRoot /home/user/sites/wiki ServerName www.example.com <Directory "/home/user/sites/*"> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews AllowOverride None Order allow,deny Allow from all  </Directory>`
`
for some reason I can acess the php page for the site from my computer ( that im hosting the site from in a browser) however when I try to access the site from any other device, all I get is a default "it works page". Any ideas how to fix this. (for reference I have tried accessing the site from an android phone in duckduckgo and firefox)

I have tried defining  `DirectotyIndex index.php` and also using a .htaccess file as well however netiher of these seem to be a solution. The problem is just so weird because I can access the sites php page from my computer but just not from other devices

Comment: Try `<VirtualHost *:81>`

Comment: thank you!!! That solved my problem, I guess that config only made the site available from the host machine

Comment: Exactly that. I've added an answer accordingly. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

`<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:81>` means "if the incoming request comes from 127.0.0.1 and is on port 81, use this virtualhost".

As requests from your other devices don't come from 127.0.0.1, they don't get routed to this virtualhost. `<VirtualHost *:81>` will apply this routing to *all* requests for port 81.